# Use Typescript into Angular 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

Using Angular 1.5.5, I try to use Typescript so I configured gulp tasks successfully ; now I try to make a service in typescript with this code in SampleService.ts:

```
module app {
    class SampleService {
        constructor() {
        }

        public toto() :void {
            console.log('test');
        }
    }
    angular.module("app").service("SampleService", [SampleService]);
}
```

Otherwhere I have :

```
angular.module('app',
[ 'ngMaterial',
  'ngAnimate',
 ....
```

In order to declares routes:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('myapp', {
        url: '',
        controller: 'MainController as vm',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/main.html',
        abstract: true
    })
    .state('myapp.search', {
        url: '/',
        controller: 'SearchController as vm',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/partials/search.html'
    })
```

Without this service declaration, everything is working fine. Now with SampleService declared this way, I get:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/ng/areq?p0=MainController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
minErr/<@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
assertArg@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1880:11
```

Even if the service is not injected, it seems to break my application. Any idea of what wrong I did?

Comment: controller: MainController, controllerAs: 'vm',

Comment: Just for the sake of it, can you remove the braces when registering the service?  '.service("sampleService", SampleService);

Comment: Can you post output JS file compiled from TypeScript service

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

There is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dTj0JEKTptGvqrdm0UR9?p=preview)
Just register controller as you did with a service:

```
module app {
    class SampleService {
        constructor() {
        }

        public toto() :void {
            console.log('test');
        }
    }
    angular.module("app").service("SampleService", [SampleService]);

    class MainController  {

        static $inject = ["$scope", "SampleService"];
        constructor(
            protected $scope, 
            protected SampleService: SampleService) {

            this.init();
        }

        public init() :void {
            this.SampleService.toto();
        }
    }
    angular.module("app").controller("MainController", MainController);
}
```

and states as they are *(just I do prefer some url, other then string empty)*

```
.state('myapp', {
    url: '/myapp',
    controller: 'MainController as vm',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/main.html',
    abstract: true
})
.state('myapp.search', {
    url: '/search',
    controller: 'SearchController as vm',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/partials/search.html'
})
```

and this will work:

```
<a ui-sref="myapp.search">
```

Check it [here in action](http://plnkr.co/edit/dTj0JEKTptGvqrdm0UR9?p=preview)